# I need to center 2 images side by side (warp) & also change images on hover, seems like I can't do both at the same time

Tags: html, css

I need to **center** images **side by side** (warp) & also be able to **change images on hover**, seems like I can't do both at the same time.

Here is what is have tried:
The first part is the centering part; it works.
The 3rd part is the hover part; that works too but only if justified to the left 
and the 2nd part is both and it gets crazy when I hover over.

```css
a img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}
a:hover img:last-child {
  display: block;  
}
a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;  
}


.fblogo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 200px;    
}
    
#images{ text-align: center; }
#images2{ text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="images">
  
    <img class="fblogo" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141420_2072_Artboard-55.png" />
   <img class="fblogo" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141436_2072_Artboard-50.png" />
    
</div>

<div id="images2">
  <a href="https://cs13498732.churchspring.org/get-involved/breakway/">
    <img class="fblogo" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141420_2072_Artboard-55.png" />
    <img class="fblogo" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141416_2072_Artboard-56.png" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/OlympiaHaacht">
    <img class="fblogo" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141436_2072_Artboard-50.png" />
    <img class="fblogo" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141441_2072_Artboard-49.png" />
  </a>
</div>

<div id="images3">
<a href="https://cs13498732.churchspring.org/get-involved/calvary-kids/">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141420_2072_Artboard-55.png" alt="" style="float: left; margin: auto;">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141416_2072_Artboard-56.png" alt="" style="background-color: initial; float: left; margin: auto;">
</a>
<a href="https://cs13498732.churchspring.org/get-involved/breakway/">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141436_2072_Artboard-50.png" alt="" style="float: left; margin: 0px 30px 30px 0px;">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141441_2072_Artboard-49.png" alt="" style="float: left; margin: 0px 30px 30px 0px;">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `display:block` to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: @WaisKamal Dude!!!! Thank you so much, you fixed it!

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution which uses a Flexbox to centre the content automatically

HTML

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div>
    <a href="https://cs13498732.churchspring.org/get-involved/calvary-kids/">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141420_2072_Artboard-55.png" alt="" style="float: left; margin: auto;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141416_2072_Artboard-56.png" alt="" style="background-color: initial; float: left; margin: auto;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://cs13498732.churchspring.org/get-involved/breakway/">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141436_2072_Artboard-50.png" alt="" style="float: left; margin: 0px 30px 30px 0px;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://d1fzhre25nnjsm.cloudfront.net/483141441_2072_Artboard-49.png" alt="" style="float: left; margin: 0px 30px 30px 0px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}
a:hover img:last-child {
  display: block;  
}
a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;  
}
.fblogo {
  height: 200px;    
}
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

View On JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/MrGreyKnight/qmsfj89h/4/

Nice Guide to Flexboxes :)
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/